# Proving that a function is nowhere differentiable so it cannot be analytically continued.

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is a problem from Stein and Shakarchi
[image: page1]

Where the definiton of analytic continuity is given here
[image]

This is what I have so far. At the unit circle, $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n \alpha} e^{i 2^n}$.
If g(z) is analytic, then $\forall z \in D$ the coefficients are given by $2^{-n \alpha} = \frac{g^(n)(z_0)}{n!}$.Can I somehow show that these $g^(n)$ don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of proving the result is as follows: suppose that $z_0\in C$ is a regular point. Then there's an open neighbourhood of $z_0$ such that $f$ has an analytic extension there.  Thanks to [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem), it is easy to see that such an extension must satisfy, on the intersection of the neighbourhood with the unit circle $$f(e^{i\vartheta})=\sum 2^{-n\alpha}e^{i2^n\vartheta}=\sum\frac{\cos(2^n\vartheta)}{2^{n\alpha}}+i\sum\frac{\sin(2^n\vartheta)}{2^{n\alpha}}$$

Both the real and the immaginary part of $f$ are [Weierstrass' functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) and so are continuous and non-differentiable. Thus $f$ cannot be analytically continued on any point of the unit circle (since $f$ has to be smooth at regular points).

Comment: In the application of Abel's theorem above, the coefficients of $f(e^{i \theta})$ are $2^{-n \alpha}$ but you have taken $e^{i2^{n}\theta}$. Can you explain why @Caffeine?

Comment: A  Weierstrauss' function according to the link, is given by $f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }a^{n}\cos(b^{n}\pi x),$. n is not odd here. @Caffeine

Comment: @curious_analyst Abel's theorem states that, if $g(z)=\sum a_n z^n$ converges for $z_0$, then in a stoltz sector we have $\lim_{z\to z_0}g(z)=g(z_0)$.  I simply applied it to a point in the unit circle, thus of the form $e^{i\vartheta}$. About your second comment: what do you mean by "$n$ is not odd here"? We are summing on $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

Comment: What I mean is according to the wiki link n needs to be odd to be a Weirstrauss function. In this case it is even. What is a stoltz  sector?

Comment: how do I prove it extends continuously to the unit circle. Is it enough to show the function is continuous there?@Caffeine

Comment: @curious_analyst The continuity up to the boundary (included) follows from the total convergence of the power series on the closed circle

Comment: Thanks @Caffeine

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is to use the fact that if an analytic function $h$ is analytically continuable at a point $|\alpha|=1$ then all its derivatives are (why?).

Picking an integer $k >\alpha$ and taking $g_1=zg', g_2=zg_1',...g_k=zg_{k-1}'$ one gets that the function $g_k(z)=\sum 2^{(k-\alpha)n} z^{2^n}$ is continuable at $\alpha$, while it is very easy to show that for any $\beta$ root of unity of order some power of $2$, $|g_k(r\beta)| \to \infty, r \to 1$ and such are dense on the unit circle contradicting that $g_k$ is analytic (hence continuous) on a neighborhood of $\alpha$, so at some such root of unity

Comment: the answer to your question (why?) is because it is analytic at that point,so the power series expansion exists.

Comment: Yes that's the idea that analytic continuation is extremely strong; the example above is differentiable on the circle (wr circle parameter so one variable) a lot of times for large $\alpha$ and with more care can be tweaked to be made $C^{\infty}$ but still not continuable anywhere on the circle